# Access running java program from shell command

Tags: java, unix, command-line, nio

I am looking for a way to access running java program from command line. The best woud be something that does the following:

Starting java app:

```
bash$java -jar MyBundle.jar App
```

Accessing app:

```
bash$test.sh param1 param2
```

So, `test.sh` calls `App` from `MyBundle.jar` somehow and passes values `param1` & `param2`.

Important: I am looking for very fast approach. `App` hold database connection and it is very expensive to start `App` every time I need access do DB.

I need solution that will work in Ubuntu and Debian. If it will work on Mac - great.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Reading from `System.in` is not an option?

Comment: So, you want to send commands to a running process?

Comment: joe776 - do you have any examples? Would be great...

Comment: McDowell - right. And somehow reply to requests...

Comment: I know about JMX - but maybe there is an easier way? *nix way? JMX examples are welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to take a client-server approach. You app is the server, it runs as a background process and listens for connections on some port. And your client makes requests to the server and gets back the response.

A fast and simple way of implementing this in java would be to wrap your app in the [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) servlet container. You could set it up to return JSON responses for example, which are easy to process.

Comment: Maybe maybe... But without JSON and Jetty maybe

Comment: Any examples how to integrate jetty into the project? Would be nice if it will start as a part of the service I am developing?

Comment: RMI is another option. Arguably easier (the OP doesn't mind tight coupling, I think). Introduction: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html

Comment: @MinimeDJ have a look at the jetty documentation too, see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

Comment: I think RMI wint give me enough speed at start-up. It is because there are two java programs involved... Should be only one :-)

Comment: Running a java program that sends an RMI from the command line would take less than 0.1s.  Is it really a problem?

Answer (score 1):

It would be quite straightforward to open a TCP/IP socket and use `netcat` from the shell.

Java code

```
final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9050);
while (true) {
    final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    java.util.logging.Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Accepted");
    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            socket.getInputStream()));
    final String input = br.readLine();
    final BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        bw.write("You said [" + input + "]");
    bw.flush();
    socket.close();
}
```

Shell code

```
echo 'bla' | nc localhost 9050
```

You'd need to muck around with threads to keep the sockets open to serve multiple requests.

Comment: > You need to much around with threads - this is why i suggested Jetty in my answer as this is all handled for you.

Comment: Yeah, good point. I guess it depends on the complexity of the app. What's a simple way of communicating with an http server via a shell command?

Comment: telnet or netcat, but ideally you'd write a simple client, probably mush easier re parsing/processing the response

Comment: Ok, it works with Jetty now. I also have choosen Jetty because of threads. Thanks for good idea anyway!